# Which continuous, differentiable a.e. functions have $f’(x) = f(x)$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

**Question:**

Consider the set of continuous, differentiable a.e. functions from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Can we characterise the subset of these that satisfy $f’(x) = f(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb R$?

*Remarks:*

*1) The problem can be thought of as a weakening of the defining ODE for the exponential function - $f’(x) = f(x)$ everywhere, which is solvable only by piecewise combinations of $Ce^x$ and the zero function.*

*2) If $f$ is a solution, then so is $f + g$ for any $g$ continuous and differentiable a.e. with $g’ = 0$ a.e.*

*3) The full measure subset on which $f’ = f$ can in general be smaller than the full measure set on which $f’$ is defined.*

Comment: This holds if and only if $g(x) = e^{-x} f(x)$ satisfies $g' = 0$ almost everywhere. Or, in other word, $f(x) = e^x g(x)$ with $g' = 0$ almost everywhere. Is this an answer you were looking for?

Comment: For slight clarification: when you say "continuous, differentiable a.e.", does that mean that it is differentiable a.e. and continuous, or that a.e. applies to both continuity and differentiability? From the "piecewise combinations" thing, it sounds like you mean a.e. to apply to both.

Comment: So set of solutions is dense in $C^0$ (I erroneously believed a bootstrap argument started from the fact that f' was equal a.e. to a continuous function...)

Comment: @user44191 Ah I mean the former, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki that would indeed be a full classification! However I think there are more possibilities…

Comment: How can it have more possibilities if this is if and only if?

Comment: I mean that I think that the “only if” might not be true.

Comment: I would need to see a proof of that part…

Comment: @NateRiver: I may be wrong, but, for a given $x$, $f'(x)$ exists iff $g'(x)$ exists, and $f'(x)=f(x)$ if and only if $g'(x)=0$, so the answer really seems to be that simple. Does this make sense? (It's Saturday morning here, so I may need another cup of coffee to get things right.)

Comment: This is just a (pointwise) "derivative of a product" theorem

Comment: Huh.. I can’t find anything wrong with your proof… but I seem to have an example that is not of that form either - let $g$ be the Cantor function and take $f(x) = e^x \int_0^x e^{-s} g(s) \, ds + g(x)$. Then $f’(x) = e^x \int_0^x e^{-s} g(s) \, ds + e^x [e^{-x}g(x)] = f(x)$, a.e. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @NateRiver: For this $f$ the corresponding $g(x)=e^{-x} f(x)$ satisfies $g(x) = \int_0^x e{-s}C(s)ds+e^{-x}C(x)$, where $C$ is the Cantor function, and clearly $g'(x)=0$ almost everywhere. In fact, $g(x) = e^{-x}C(x) - \int_0^x C(s) de^{-s} = \int_0^x e^{-s} dC(s)$, and it is easy to see that $g(x) = \phi(C(x))$, where, if I am not mistaken, $\phi'(t)=e^{-C^{-1}(t)}$.

Comment: @NateRiver Your example is of the form $e^xh(x)$ where $h'=0$ a.e., namely $h(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ (obviously). You can check directly $h'=0$ a.e. in this case

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something like that. Should have just done the calculation. Nice solve anyway!

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I recommend you post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $g(x) = e^{-x} f(x)$, so that $f(x) = e^x g(x)$. For a given $x$, $f'(x)$ exists if and only if $g'(x)$ exists, and $g'(x) = e^{-x} (f'(x) - f(x))$. In particular, $f'(x) = f(x)$ if and only if $g'(x) = 0$.

It follows that $f$ is necessarily of the form $f(x) = e^x g(x)$, where $g$ satisfies $g'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: $g'(x)=0$ almost everywhere (a.e.) if and only if $g(x)=C$ a.e. for some constant $C$. Therefore, the solutions of $y'=y$ a.e. are given by $y=Ce^x$ a.e. for some constant $C$.

Comment: @BlackMild: That is true if, for example, $g$ is absolutely continuous (by Lebesgue integration), or if $g$ is differentiable everywhere (by Henstock–Kurzweil integration). However, if we only require that $g'$ exists a.e. and it is zero a.e., $g$ may fail to be constant. An example is provided by the [Cantor's (or Devil's) staircase function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).